# how to generate the same random number in two different environments?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, environment

I compiled exactly the same code that generate random numbers in two different environments ( Linux and visual studio ). But I noticed that the outputs are different. I searched online and understand that the two implementations generate different random numbers. But I need the Linux to generate the same random numbers of that generated by visual studio.

So, how to let the two different environments ( Linux and visual studio ) generate the same random numbers. Any ideas.

My code:

```
void mix_dataset(array<array<int, 20>, 5430>& array_X_dataset, array<int, 5430>& array_Y_dataset) {
   // size_t len = array_X_dataset.size();
  //  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
       // size_t swap_index = rand() % len;  
   
    mt19937 engine;
    engine.seed(3);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5430; ++i) {
    size_t swap_index = engine() %  5430;
        if (i == swap_index)
            continue;

        array<int, 20> data_point{  };
        data_point = array_X_dataset[i];
        array_X_dataset[i] = array_X_dataset[swap_index];
        array_X_dataset[swap_index] = data_point;
        int Y = array_Y_dataset[i];
        array_Y_dataset[i] = array_Y_dataset[swap_index];
        array_Y_dataset[swap_index] = Y;
    }
}
int main(){

srand(3);
mix_dataset(array_X_dataset, array_Y_dataset);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a the mersenne twister it has reproducable output (it is standardized).
Use the same seed on 2 machines and you're good to go.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 engine;

    engine.seed(1);

    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << engine() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can verify it here, https://godbolt.org/z/j5r6ToGY7, just select different compilers and check the output

Comment: Just like the fact that `rand` is in the standard doesn't mean you should use it, just the mere fact that MT is in the standard doesn't mean you should use it. It may be OK to make those tradeoffs or it may not be. I tend to avoid it [due to known problems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.06437.pdf)

Comment: thank you for your answer. So where to include your solution in my code. Could you please modify my code with your suggestion.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Comment noted. Sure all pseudo random numbers have issues, specialy if things need to be really secure. And indeed I did not ask for the intended use, and I assumed this would be good enough for his use case.

Comment: @user16767585 P Kramer provided enough information for you to be able to use this in your code.

Comment: thank you for tour reply. Yes I know his answer is helpful. But I tried to included it in my code and still have problem. I think I include it in wrong way

Comment: @PKramer I added these lines of code to my original code and it gave me `An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.`

Comment: @PKramer The problem is solved thank you very much . I updated my code with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the standard library function implementations offered by the two platforms differ, you'll need to decide on a PRNG that whose output given the same seed is the same on both platforms.

Standard C provides very little in the way of guarantees when it comes to the quality of the PRNG exposed by `rand` anyway and serious applications should stay away from that.

Whatever the critiques, you would be in a better position using [PCG](https://www.pcg-random.org/index.html), for example, since you do not seem to need cryptographic quality.

In addition, avoid

```
        size_t swap_index = rand() % len;
```

as randomness may suffer. You can instead use rejection sampling if the library you choose does not offer an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for reply, But I am not sure how to fix my code to meet the same outputs as you suggested.

Comment: 1) Decide on an implementation. 2) Use the implementation.

Comment: I want  to use the same implementation in my code. which is `rand() and srand ()`

Comment: Since the implementation of `rand` differs across platforms even though the ***name*** of the function is the same, you have to choose to use something ***else*** which produces the same results in both environments. I made a suggestion, but, ultimately, you should evaluate the alternatives and pick one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pseudorandom number with a known algorithm, you must choose them both explicitly with the C++ [library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

You can't do this with [`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand), because it will vary between C library implementations.

And please distinguish between pseudorandom number generators (which will produce the same sequence from the same seed) and random ones, which are vanishingly unlikely to coincide.